# Sublime Text 3: There are no packages available for installation

Tags: sublime-text, windows-10

Всем привет!

Обновился позавчера на Windows 10 и после обновления получил такую проблему в Sublime: *Package Control: There are no packages available for installation.*

Как быть c проблемой и как можно решить?

Если нужна дополнительная информация - готов ее дать, но пока не очень понимаю в каком направлении копать и что искать.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Говорят, надо в файл hosts прописать строчку: 50.116.34.243 sublime.wbond.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что package control не смог достучаться до сервера и скачать реестр пакетов.

Стоит проверить:

1. Нет ли проблем с сервером (вот тут статусы пишут https://twitter.com/Package_Control )
2. Посмотреть Debug log: https://packagecontrol.io/docs/troubleshooting
3. Посмотреть, что говорит ваш браузер про HTTPS на сайте https://packagecontrol.io/ (должен быть "зеленый" EV-сертификат, если нет - скорее всего у вас офисная сеть, которая делает mitm SSL-трафика)
4. Изучать кучу ишей от людей с этой проблемой, там автор неустанно дает советы, может найдете похожую на свою: https://github.com/wbond/package_control/search?o=desc&q=There+are+no+packages+available+for+installation&s=updated&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93