# Ошибка: "There are no packages available for installation" в Sublime 3

Tags: sublime-text

Столкнулся с проблемой, что перестала работать возможность добавления новых пакетов. При попытке запустить Install Package выходить следующее сообщение: "There are no packages available for installation". Стоит Windows 7.

Comment: дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/439047/183449